# MySQL Foreign Keys.. confused

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to understand MySQL Foreign Keys, I hope someone can help.

I have two tables with the following structures;

reports

```
+-----------+------+-----------+------------------+
|id|user_id |status|report_type|request_id        |
+-----------+------+-----------+------------------+
|                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

users

```
+-----------+------+-----------+------------------+
|id|username|f_name|l_name     |email             |
+-----------+------+-----------+------------------+
|                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I have a foreign key in the reprots table (`fk_uid`) that links the `user_id` column in the reports table to the `id` in the users table.

I want to run a MySQL Query in PHP that will pull all the reports for a given user (either by username or user_id, not sure which is best?)

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with foreign keys. Foreign keys are just a tool to enforce data integrity. You only asking how to perform a (fairly basic) SELECT query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done by simple inner join as

```
select 
users.username, 
users.f_name, 
users.l_name , 
reports.status,reports.report_type,
reports.request_id from reports
inner join users on users.id = reports.user_id
```

If you want to search for a specific user then use where condition as

```
select 
users.username, 
users.f_name, 
users.l_name , 
reports.status,
reports.report_type,
reports.request_id from reports
inner join users on users.id = reports.user_id
where users.username = 'some user name'
```

And if you want by userid then where condition is

```
where users.id = 'your user id'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to get reports and no user information then you can do a direct query to reports table if you have a user_id

Suppose you have userid in a variable in $userid

like

`select * from reports where user_id = $userid`

if you want data from both tables then you need to do a join like this

**Reports for a specific user:**

`select r.*, u.* from reports r, users u where r.user_id = $userid
  and r.user_id = u.id`

**Reports for all users**

`select r.*, u.* from reports r, users u where r.user_id = u.id`

if you want  to learn more about joins the visit this link

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/